# How do i can create a payfort test account?

Tags: payment-gateway, payment, payfort

I have researched a lot to get a payfort test account. Seems to me this is the link https://www.payfort.com/test-account/ but it is down.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this for test account. https://testfort.payfort.com/

Id & password will not be same. you need to ask them for that.

Comment: Ask them through which channel? @team-appbirds